# chrome web app trusted tester asked to log in repeatedly, can't ever download app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

I have tried to give other users at our company permission to use a packaged app I am developing. 2 users have had no problem - they log in (through the company Gmail), go to the link I sent them, get the CWStore page for the app, click on "+", & get the app installed.

This has worked with both the "Trusted Testers" option set, and also with the "Anyone who has the link" option set.

Another user gets trapped in the following loop:
- click on the link I sent
- gets the store page for the app, clicks on "+"
- gets a page asking him to log in
- he logs in, & gets a blank page with a small frame saying something like "this user is already logged in on this machine" in the upper right corner
- he goes back to the store page, clicks on "+"
- gets a page asking him to log in ...

This is embarrassing because the user in question is the President of the company :)

This has happened to him while both the "Trusted Testers"and the "anyone with the link" options were set.

I have also tried un-publishing and then re-publishing the packaged app.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!